# How do I read a list of JSON files from file in python?

Tags: json, list, io, python-2.7

I have a list of JSON files saved to disk that I would like to read. Sometimes the JSON files span more than one line and so, I think that a simple list comprehension that loops over `open(file,'rb').readlines()` will fail.

The files are surrounded in brackets and so passing them to `json.load` or `json.loads` won't work.

An example file would be:

```
[{key:value,key2:value2},{morekeys:morevalues},{evenmorekeys,evenmorevalues}]
```

What is the best/ most Pythonic way to read a saved list of JSON entries when the entries span more than one line?

Comment: Can you show a snippet of what  your files look like? Why wouldn't they be loadable json? What added invalid formatting to them? Newlines don't matter in json.

Comment: The files begin with `[` and end with `]`. Answer annotated. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: But `[]` are valid json arrays. It sounds like you have an array of objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example is valid json. `[]` define json arrays. What you have is an array of objects:

```
with open("myFile.json") as f:
    objects = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Your code work for a single file, not a list of files

Comment: @Julien the original question asked how to read a given file that defines an array of objects. The OP only referenced having multiple files with this format. Reading more than one file is not a json problem.